# Build DateTimeOffset from unspecified DateTime and Timezone name

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a DateTime dt, which has a date and time of some local instant and a String tz specifying the timezone name for that datetime. How do I get a DateTimeOffset struct fully representing the DateTime?

I can get the timezone info with `TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(csf.TimezoneName);`

but I'm now unsure how to get the DateTimeOffset I want from these two elements

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx

Comment: I guess it(`TimeZoneInfo`) has a `BaseUtcOffset` property

Comment: The problem with the BaseUtcOffset is that it doesn't take DST in to account

Comment: Use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId().  DST is not a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert a local time in a particular zone to a `DateTimeOffset` like this:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dt, tzi.GetUtcOffset(dt));
```

Just be aware that if the input time is ambiguous or invalid due to [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), it will use the zone's *standard* offset.